# Insert Outlook email into outlook task without drag and drop?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, task

I depend heavily on Outlook to organize my work. E.g I use Tasks to keep track on.. well, my tasks. Frequently I get email which I attach to the corresponding Task and then delete it from my inbox. To do this I have to open the task, drag and drop the email into the task, save and close the task and then delete the email.

I wish to make these steps with the push of a button. Is this possible even with VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `TaskItem.Attachments.Add` and pass the `MailItem` object from your Inbox.